# Android: check if my Service is running in the background

Tags: android, service

I am running a **Service** to get **Notifications** every 1 hour in my application.

The service definitely runs every 1 hr; I checked it using the Logcat.

But since I am starting this Service in the `onResume()` of my MainActivity, I want to check whether the Service is already running, and start it only if it's not running.

I used this code:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("com.android.MyApp.MyServices.NotificationsService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But I always get **false**.

So I checked what output `service.service.getClassName()` gives. And my Service is not there in the list.

Is it because my application is unknown? or something else?

Comment: Why would you need to check that the service is running? Assuming you start your service with context.startService(...) the service will only be created if its currently not running, but onStartCommand(...) of your service will always be called

Comment: Is your service listed on Settings>Applications>RunningServices ?

Answer (score 0):

I know its bit late but this answer might help others who are looking for the same.

Have you started your service by using `context.startService()`?
Make sure that the manifest file contains following:

```
<service android:name="com.android.MyApp.MyServices.NotificationsService" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context mContext) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (**HERE_YOUR_SERVICE'S_CLASS_NAME**.class.getName().equals(
                service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

// i have background GPS service and i have successfully checked that my GPS service is either running or not.

// Happy coding...